# In MVVM, when should a property by used vs a converter?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

We've had the discussion at work a few times about when to use a property in a ViewModel vs when to use a Converter.

Use a Converter when:

- it can be re-used in other places (a great example is an IsVisibilityConverter)
- it's a UI related action such as selecting toggle button based on a parameter value
- a parameter isn't needed or can be a static value

Use a ViewModel property when:

- The value depends on another property (example: duration shown in seconds depends on what the user chose in acombo box, hours, minutes, seconds)
- It needs to be unit tested
- PropertyChanged events can change its value

EDIT: I should mention that I work mainly in Silverlight. So I don't have multibinding converters out of the box and binding to the parameter doesn't work (which I think it does in WPF).
What are your thoughts?

Comment: No, you can't bind a converter parameter in WPF either...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, I try to think of `IValueConverter` as a "pure view" thing.  In this case, it should be reusable view code.  (You can also use `IMultiValueConverter` to handle many of the scenarios where you'd need "parameters", provided it's still pure view related...)

The ViewModel, on the other hand, is application specific logic.  If something relies on state that's specific to your domain, I'd rather put it directly inside of the ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

One of the common use of converter is for reuse like the commonly used BooleanToVisibilityConvertor. The other use is when you want to perform view specific things. For e.g. in your model you might have a decimal or integer value like an amount. But in the view you want to show formatted amount like $10,000,000.00. You can use a value convertor in this case. Another case is where you want to display data in different format like a rating control which can be used to display different representation in UI while storing it differently in the database.

Dates are another common place where we can use value convertors. Imagine a scenario where you want to display relative information about a task in a to do application. Based on the current data and a date associated with a task you can display different status like occurs today, tomorrow, this week, this month etc or occured in past.

You'll use properties when there is not conversion required between the value that is ther ein the model and what needs to be displayed in the view.